# How would you include a pull_request_template in multiple repos?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, readme

I'm working with a software development team that wants a standard pull_request_template.md file included across multiple repositories (the file is a standard checklist for authors and reviewers to go through when doing a PR).

If I want to change this file and have it update in an automatic or semi-automatic manner across multiple repos, how would I do that? Do I need to start using [git-submodules](https://github.blog/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're happy for this to be a default for all repos in your organisation, you can create a repo called .github with a default pull request template:

https://github.blog/changelog/2019-02-21-organization-wide-community-health-files/

Unfortunately without some external tooling like git-submodules there's no way to share this across only certain repos however.